# Form POST with rememberme authentication redirects in stead of processes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Security with rememberme authentication.

Whenever I post a FORM and my session is lost in between adding content to the form and submitting it, I get redirected to targetUrl that is used by Spring Security.

What I want to happen is for the original POST request to be processed as expected by the user after a successful rememberme authentication. What would be the best way to capture the POST request in the LoginSuccessHandler and process it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` bean as the authentication-success-handler-ref in your rememberMe configuration.

Spring Security will remember your original POST request inside `ExceptionTranslationFilter` (and store it using `RequestCache`). Once you authenticate, the successHandler will make a redirect to the original URL (based on data in the `RequestCache`). The redirect is then intercepted by the `RequestCacheAwareFilter` (which is automatically added with your <security:http> configuration) and it will replace data of the request with content from your original POST.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go since it doesn't seem to be happening